# Threejs How to set camera for large scale objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am rendering a cityscape using Three.js. When attempting to view the scene I can't seem to get the camera near/far settings correct to render the whole scene. When I increase the camera's far plane - I am able to see the model, but it appears blue (image below) until I zoom into it. Is there a way to see the entire model without having to zoom super close to the scene?

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene()

scene.background = new THREE.Color(33,33,33);

var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xe8ecff, 1.4)
ambient.name = 'ambientLight'
scene.add(ambient)

var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xfff1f1, 0.7)
directionalLight1.name = 'directionalLight1'
directionalLight1.position.set(-1500, 900, 1500)
directionalLight1.castShadow = true
scene.add(directionalLight1)

directionalLight1.shadow.camera.right = 2500
directionalLight1.shadow.camera.left = -2500
directionalLight1.shadow.camera.top = 2500
directionalLight1.shadow.camera.bottom = -2500
directionalLight1.shadow.camera.near = 0
directionalLight1.shadow.camera.far = 5000

var shadowCameraHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper(directionalLight1.shadow.camera)
shadowCameraHelper.visible = false
shadowCameraHelper.name = 'directionalLight1Helper'
scene.add(shadowCameraHelper)

var directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x87c0ff, 0.2)
directionalLight2.name = 'directionalLight2'
directionalLight2.position.set(1, 1, -1)
scene.add(directionalLight2)

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement  );

camera.position.set(-400, 700, 500)

function animate (){
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  controls.update();

  stats.update()

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

animate();

var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader
loader.load("example_mesh.json", 

function(obj){

  var bb = new THREE.Box3()

  bb.expandByObject(obj)

  var center = new THREE.Vector3()

  bb.getCenter(center)

  let modelSettings = { x: -center.x, y: center.y, z: -center.z }

  let cameraRadius = this.boundingBox.geometry.boundingSphere.radius/2 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5))

  obj.position.set(modelSettings.x, modelSettings.y, modelSettings.z)

  camera.position.set(cameraRadius, cameraRadius, cameraRadius);

  controls.target.set(0,modelSettings.y, 0)

  controls.update()

  scene.add(obj)

}, onProgress, onError)
```

[image: Actual]
[image: Expected]

Comment: Does your `shadowCameraHelper` provide any clues? Does it look like it's actually working over the intended area? Also, you're setting up your light to cause shadows, but you aren't setting anything to cast/receive them. Ensure you set `Object3D.receiveShadow`/`Object3D.receiveShadow` on your `Mesh`es, where appropriate.

Comment: Hello, the `shadowCameraHelper` does seem like it is working. When I zoom far enough into the scene shadows appear correctly. I exported the BufferGeometries with materials with `receiveShadow`/`castShadow` as `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an object is being clipped out of the camera's focal length, you can use [Object3D.scale](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.scale). AFter adjusting this scaler value the entire building is visible in the camera on load and does not get clipped. You adjust the objects scale during the loading callback.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene()

scene.background = new THREE.Color(33,33,33);

var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xe8ecff, 1.4)
ambient.name = 'ambientLight'
scene.add(ambient)

var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xfff1f1, 0.7)
directionalLight1.name = 'directionalLight1'
directionalLight1.position.set(-1500, 900, 1500)
directionalLight1.castShadow = true
scene.add(directionalLight1)

directionalLight1.shadow.camera.right = 2500
directionalLight1.shadow.camera.left = -2500
directionalLight1.shadow.camera.top = 2500
directionalLight1.shadow.camera.bottom = -2500
directionalLight1.shadow.camera.near = 0
directionalLight1.shadow.camera.far = 5000

var shadowCameraHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper(directionalLight1.shadow.camera)
shadowCameraHelper.visible = false
shadowCameraHelper.name = 'directionalLight1Helper'
scene.add(shadowCameraHelper)

var directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x87c0ff, 0.2)
directionalLight2.name = 'directionalLight2'
directionalLight2.position.set(1, 1, -1)
scene.add(directionalLight2)

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement  );

camera.position.set(-400, 700, 500)

function animate (){
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  controls.update();

  stats.update()

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

animate();

var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader
loader.load("example_mesh.json", 

function(obj){
  // adjust the scale of the object in the scene.
  // default scale is (1,1,1) 
  obj.scale.set( .1, .1, .1 );

  var bb = new THREE.Box3()

  bb.expandByObject(obj)

  var center = new THREE.Vector3()

  bb.getCenter(center)

  let modelSettings = { x: -center.x, y: center.y, z: -center.z }

  let cameraRadius = this.boundingBox.geometry.boundingSphere.radius/2 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5))

  obj.position.set(modelSettings.x, modelSettings.y, modelSettings.z)

  camera.position.set(cameraRadius, cameraRadius, cameraRadius);

  controls.target.set(0,modelSettings.y, 0)

  controls.update()

  scene.add(obj)

}, onProgress, onError)
```